# Roman style of an author field in biblatex's bibstyle GOST

Tags: biblatex

How to apply roman style for author field in biblatex gost? Now it is italic one.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = uk_UA
% !BIB program = biber

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.bib}
    @BOOK{texbook,
        author = "Knuth, D. E.",
        title= {\TeX Book},
        publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
        year = {1984}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=gost-numeric, babel=other, isbn=true, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{file.bib}

\begin{document}

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to stick with a general GOST/ГОСТ bibliography and only want to change the formatting of the name from italics to Roman, you need to redefine the special name formatting macro `\mkbibhdnamefamily`. The standard styles use `\mkbibnamefamily` instead, and that is also what `biblatex-gost` uses in other places, but in the initial heading position special `\mkbibhdname...` macros are used.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric, autolang=other, isbn=true, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibhdnamefamily}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{knuth:ct:a}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]